# How to Change the DevExpress Split Container Control Pannel Name?

Tags: c#, devexpress, splitcontainer

Any body please help how to change the DevExpress splitContainer control Panel Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither standard SplitContainer nor our SplitContainerControl allows you to change the Name property  of their Panels.